# EXECUÇÃO DE DATAS SQL - ODBC

Tags: php, sql, oracle, odbc

Eu estou com dúvida no formato de data que o ODBC executa. Tentei de todas as maneiras e nada. Essa Query executa normal se eu insiro somente o código, mas quando quero inserir datas ela não executa. Acredito que é por conta do formato. Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
$Query = "INSERT INTO TABLE(CODIGO, DATA_CRIADO) values (300, '2017-01-01')";
ODBC_exec($conn, $Query);
```

Comment: Tenta pegar o erro com `var_dump(odbc_errormsg($conn));` sua conexão está como autocommit?

Comment: Sim, a conexão está com autocommit

Comment: Em qual linha entra essa sintaxe?

Comment: pode ser `ODBC_exec($conn, $Query) or die(odbc_errormsg($conn));`

Comment: Deu certo. ORA-01843: not a valid month

Comment: Achei, ele só aceita o mês escrito. Exemplo ''10/may/2017"

Comment: use a função TO_DATE com formatação para inserir, fazendo com que sempre seja convertido antes https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php